# MySQL connection not working when computer is locked

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection-timeout

I am having a weird issue, haven't had this happen before, but my database is on a computer at my work, and when I leave at the end of the day, the computer autolocks, and when this happens, I am unable to connect to the database anymore.

I have to login before it will allow the connection again.  Is there a way I can make it work no matter what? I need the connection 24/7, and this is making it really hard to code at home.

I am using Windows Server 2012, and I am using PHP to connect, but I have done tests, when the computer lock at night, the connection to the server stops, and when I go in and unlock it during the day, the connection is available.  I have all of the "major" operating systems, Mac, Windows, and Linux/Ubuntu, and I have the ability to view the site on Mobile phones during the day too.  As soon as the computer locks (like the user is inactive so long it requires a password to log back on), the connection becomes unavailable.

Comment: Do not work from home! :)

Comment: You might have better luck asking on http://superuser.com/ - the answer is going to be OS-specific. The operating system will need to be configured to *not* go to sleep or shut-down hard drives when locked.

Comment: Err, what operating system do you use at work? (Please edit into your question rather than appending details in the comments, thanks). It may be better, in any case, for you to move this database to a proper server.

Comment: os? how does it lock? how do you connect ?

Comment: See if you can't set up your workstation to allow remote login, and login from your home computer. You could do all your work from within the RDC (although a large IDE might make it slow), or at least wake it up that way. Also make sure your computer doesn't go into hibernation (evil) or sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure MySQL is running as a service, and runs under a system account and not a user account. It could also be a system issue where the network access drops once a user is not logged in.

Look in the services manager and check MySQL's settings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ports are being blocked, make sure that there aren't any scheduled tasks that block ports when the computer is locked. Or go to the firewall advanced options and make a rule to make sure the ports are always open.